# Power automate errorCode": "INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT" "The email address for the recipient is invalid. The recipient Id follows." }

Tags: docusignapi, power-automate

I created a flow in Power Automate in which I am using DocuSign and I am passing the same recipient to receive the mail but I am getting the error {
"errorCode": "INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT",
"message": "The email address for the recipient is invalid. The recipient Id follows."
}

The flow must send an email with the file that must be signed

Comment: Did you use the out-of-the-box DocuSign Connector, or did you create your own using the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have more than one recipient?
Or that you are mistakenly passing the wrong email address?
This error is very self-explanatory and means an invalid email address was provided for one of the recipients. You need to double check the information you entered into the envelopes. Email addresses must be in the format of X@Y.Z

Comment: I am sending the same email as the recipient but I still have the same problem since it only gives me an error when sending the envelope through Power Automate. I tried sending the typed email, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the email address from? Have you tried hard coding the email address into the docusign action as opposed to getting a variable (Eg. from sharepoint or other source)? Trying to pin-point the cause here.